# Looking for mathematical paradoxes in Poker

Tags: poker-theory, poker-strategy, all-in, ev

I have been working on mathematical paradoxes.

I am looking for paradoxical situations in Poker for a deep study. I found things, like Morton's Theorem, Implicit Collusion or "all in" strategy, could you help me to find more?

Comment: I'm not certain this type of question is a good fit for this site, although it is interesting! It could be a good jumping off point for generating some extra questions on poker.se. For that reason I hope you get some good answers ;)

Comment: A paradox is when one uses generally acceptable logic to, seemingly, soundly conclude something that is prima-facie illogical. Perhaps apply Zeno's paradox to pushing all in? Read out an equation that incorrectly subtracted, or divided as a story. Here is an example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_dollar_riddle

Comment: Probably a little bit late: Do situations where ICM advises you to fold aces in Holdem qualify?

Comment: Would you make a distinction between a paradox and something which is just highly counter-intuitive?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is really a paradox, but...

In a heads-up game your opponent truthfully confides in you that he is playing a 100% range.

So you think to yourself, "Great, from now on I will play a 70% range and I will be profitable because I’m ahead of his range."

You are dealt a new hand and see that it is at the bottom of your range, but you no-longer want to play the hand because it is behind most of your opponents range.

Comment: Not seeing how 69% is behind a random hand (50%).

Comment: @paparazzo because 69 > 50.  Isn't that the definition of being behind?

Comment: Sure not my definition.

Comment: I think we might be looking at it from opposite ends. I meant 69th percentile as in a low quality hand. Not a high quality. Perhaps I should have written it as 31st percentile? Does that help?

Comment: Playing the bottom of a 70% range is worse than playing the average of a 100% range

Comment: OK I can see looking at it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a paradox as much as counter-intuitive, but according to Phil Gordon, a rare case of over-cards being a slight favorite to a pocket pair is JTs vs. 55.

Comment: That's just one example of the not-really-a-paradox of the non-transitive value of starting hands. Another is  22 > AK > JTs > 22.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker :o could you send me a link regarding that? Sounds interesting.

Comment: (haha sorry for the late! this question was bumped and I read it just now)

Answer (score 0):

Ace high straight is highest but it is actually easier to make because there are no blockers above.

To me this is a [Best hand versus AA](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/8848/best-hand-versus-aa) as every way I look at it it seems like 67s should be better.

Comment: How come AKQJT is easier to make than KQJT9? or indeed any other specified set of 5 different ranks?

Answer (score -2):

How almost all hands have at least a 33 percent chance of winning in a showdown against a pre-flop raiser. But yet they rarely actually win 33 percent of the time.